# Large raster frequency table / counts

Tags: r, frequency, raster, gdal

I try to calculate the frequency/count of pixel values of a raster in R using freq().
Create two example rasters for comparison:

```
library(raster)
RastSmall <- raster(nrow=70, ncol=70) 
RastBig   <- raster(nrow=7000, ncol=7000) 
set.seed(0)
RastSmall[] <- round(runif(1:ncell(r_hr), 1, 5))
RastBig[] <- round(runif(1:ncell(r_hr), 1, 5))
```

Get the pixel count using freq()

```
freq(RastSmall)
value    count
[1,]     1  6540000
[2,]     2 12150000
[3,]     3 12140000
[4,]     4 11720000
[5,]     5  6450000
```

However, it is a fairly large file and takes extremely long, i.e. up to hours. Is there a faster way in R? 
Here the speed difference for a small and a large raster:

```
system.time(freq(RastSmall))
  user  system elapsed 
  0.008   0.000   0.004 
system.time(freq(RastBig))
  user  system elapsed 
  40.484   0.964  41.445
```

Is there a way to speed this up? Alternatively can this be done in the command line using something like gdal tools?

Comment: Read [ask] then post the required [mcve].

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: I can't tell what in your question is input vs output vs code and I don't see anything saying what your algorithm should be to do the transofrmation but I see you've deleted the `awk` tag now and just want an `R` answer so maybe it'll all make perfect sense to an `R` expert. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly that last week, however I couldn't find other faster ways to do it in R.   I've tried to do it with the `rqgis` package by calling the `r.report` of GRASS.  It works but was slower than the R native function.  Maybe you'll have a better luck.  Here is my code with grass in case you want to try it:

```
library(RQGIS)
monqgis <- set_env("C:\\Mrnmicro\\Applic\\OSGeo4W")
find_algorithms(search_term = "report", qgis_env = monqgis)
get_usage(alg = "grass7:r.report", qgis_env = monqgis)
params <- get_args_man(alg = "grass7:r.report", qgis_env = monqgis)

get_usage(alg = "grass7:r.report", qgis_env = monqgis)

params$map <- classif
params$units <- 5
params$rawoutput <- "C:\\temp\\outputRQGIS_raw"
params$html <- "C:\\temp\\outputRQGIS"

system.time(asas <- run_qgis(alg = "grass7:r.report", params=params,load_output = params$OUTPUT, qgis_env = monqgis))
```

Answer (score 0):

not an amazing saving but if you getValues from your raster and then run the base::table function, it saves about 20%. My raster was c.500m cells.

```
# read in raster to obtain frequency table
r <- raster("./path/myraster.tif")

# perform tests; traditional freq() vs. getValues() & table()
require(microbenchmark)
  mbm <- microbenchmark(
    Freq = {freqf <- freq(r,useNA="no"); 
            freq.df <- data.frame(CODE=freqf[,1], N=freqf[,2]},
    GetVals = {v <- getValues(r);
               vt <- table(v); 
               getval.df <- data.frame(CODE=as.numeric(names(vt)),N=as.numeric(as.matrix(vt)))},
    times=5
  )
  mbm

Unit: seconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
    Freq 191.1649 191.8001 198.8567 192.5256 193.0986 225.6942     5
 GetVals 153.5552 154.8776 156.9173 157.0539 159.0400 160.0598     5

# check the routines have identical results
identical(freq.df,getval.df)
[1] TRUE
```

bit of a saving i guess
(N.B. the reason i make the data frames is that I go on to process the data that comes out of the frequency analysis)

Answer (score 0):

I think the most effective way to calculate that is by using [GetHistogram( )](https://gdal.org/doxygen/classGDALRasterBand.html#aa21dcb3609bff012e8f217ebb7c81953) from GDAL. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to use it from R. The closest approach is by using `gdalUtilities::gdalinfo` from R, and use the flag -hist, or hist = TRUE, but is limited the calculations between 0 - 255.
Another option is using `rasterDT::freqDT`, which is faster than regular options. Here an example:

```
library(gdalUtilities)
library(raster)
library(rasterDT)
library(microbenchmark)

RastBig   <- raster(nrow=7000, ncol=7000) 
set.seed(0)
RastBig[] <- round(runif(1:ncell(RastBig), 1, 5))
writeRaster(RastBig, filename = 'C:/temp/RastBig.tif')


mbm <- microbenchmark(times = 50,
  freq1 = freq(RastBig),
  freq2 = table(RastBig[]),
  freq3 = freqDT(RastBig),
  freq4 = ({
    
    gdalLog <- capture.output(gdalUtilities::gdalinfo(datasetname = 'C:/temp/RastBig.tif', hist = TRUE));
    (bucxml <- as.numeric(sub('buckets.+', '', grep('buckets ', gdalLog, value = TRUE))));
    (minxml <- as.numeric(gsub('.+from | to.+', '', grep('buckets ', gdalLog, value = TRUE)) ));
    (maxxml <- as.numeric(gsub('.+to |:', '', grep('buckets ', gdalLog, value = TRUE))));
    (histxml <- as.numeric(strsplit(split = '[[:space:]]', gsub("^ |^  ", "", gdalLog[grep('buckets', gdalLog)+1]))[[1]]));
    
    labs <- seq(from = minxml, to = maxxml, length.out = bucxml);
    df <- data.frame(labs, nwlab = c(ceiling(labs[1]),
                                      round(labs[2:(bucxml-1)]),
                                      floor(labs[bucxml])), 
                      val = histxml);
    hist <- aggregate(df$val, by = list(df$nwlab), sum)})
)
```

Results:

```
> freq1
 value    count
[1,]     1  6127755
[2,]     2 12251324
[3,]     3 12249376
[4,]     4 12248938
[5,]     5  6122607

> freq2

       1        2        3        4        5 
 6127755 12251324 12249376 12248938  6122607 

> freq3
   ID     freq
1:  1  6127755
2:  2 12251324
3:  3 12249376
4:  4 12248938
5:  5  6122607

> freq4
  Group.1        x
1       1  6127755
2       2 12251324
3       3 12249376
4       4 12248938
5       5  6122607


Unit: milliseconds
  expr          min           lq         mean       median        uq        max neval
 freq1 58628.486301 59100.539302 59400.304887 59383.913701 59650.412 60841.3975    50
 freq2 55912.170401 56663.025202 56954.032395 56919.905051 57202.001 58307.9500    50
 freq3  3785.767301  4006.858102  4288.699531  4292.447250  4536.382  4996.0598    50
 freq4     7.892201     8.883102     9.255641     9.154001     9.483    15.6072    50
```

EDIT: using this is quite faster than option 3:

```
rB <- raster('C:/temp/RastBig.tif')
freq3B <- freqDT(rB)
```